# How to break apart a column includes keys and values into separate columns in postgres

Tags: postgresql

I am new in postgres and basically have no experience. I have a table with a column includes key and value. I need write a query which return a table with the all the columns of the table and additional columns as key as the column name and the value under it.

My input is like:

```
id   | name|message
12478|  A  |{img_type:=png,key_id:=f235, client_status:=active, request_status:=open}
12598|  B  |{img_type:=none,address_id:=c156, client_status:=active, request_status:=closed}
```

output will be:

```
id   |name| Img_type|Key_id|address_id|Client_status|Request_status
12478|  A | png     |f235  |NULL      |active       | open
12598|  B | none    |NULL  |c156      |active       | closed
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: can you change the format of the `message` content? If that was a regular JSON structure it would be a lot easier

Comment: I have provided this data to read it and use in other program. I haven't tried to change the format. So you mean basically change the message column format to json within SELECT?

Comment: No, **store** the data as valid JSON (i.e. change your application to change the format)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only thing I can think of, is a regular expression to extract the key/value pairs.

```
select id, name, 
       (regexp_match(message, '(img_type:=)([^,}]+),{0,1}'))[2] as img_type,
       (regexp_match(message, '(key_id:=)([^,}]+),{0,1}'))[2] as key_id,
       (regexp_match(message, '(client_status:=)([^,}]+),{0,1}'))[2] as client_status,
       (regexp_match(message, '(request_status:=)([^,}]+),{0,1}'))[2] as request_status
from the_table;
```

`regexp_match` returns an array of matches. As the regex contains two groups (one for the "key" and one for the "value"), the `[2]` takes the second element of the array.

---

This is quite expensive and error prone (e.g. if any of the values contains a `,` and you need to deal with quoted values). If you have any chance to change the application that stores the value, you should seriously consider changing your code to store a proper JSON value, e.g.

```
{"img_type": "png", "key_id": "f235", "client_status": "active", "request_status": "open"}'
```

then you can use e.g. `message ->> 'img_type'` to retrieve the value for the key `img_type`

---

You might also want to consider a properly normalized table, where each of those keys is a real column.

Answer (score 0):

I can do it with function.
I am sure about the performance but here is my suggestion:

```
CREATE TYPE log_type AS (img_type TEXT, key_id TEXT, address_id TEXT, client_status TEXT, request_status TEXT);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION populate_log(data TEXT)
RETURNS log_type AS
$func$
DECLARE
    r log_type;
BEGIN
    select x.* into r
    from 
    (
        select 
            json_object(array_agg(array_data)) as json_data
        from (
            select unnest(string_to_array(trim(unnest(string_to_array(substring(populate_log.data, '[^{}]+'), ','))), ':=')) as array_data
        ) d
    ) d2,
    lateral json_to_record(json_data) as x(img_type text, key_id text, address_id text, client_status text, request_status text);
    RETURN r;
END
$func$  LANGUAGE plpgsql;


with log_data (id, name, message) as (
    values
    (12478, 'A', '{img_type:=png,key_id:=f235, client_status:=active, request_status:=open}'),
    (12598, 'B', '{img_type:=none,address_id:=c156, client_status:=active, request_status:=closed}')
)
select id, name, l.*
from log_data, lateral populate_log(message) as l;
```

What you finally write in query will be something like this, imagine that the data is in a table named `log_data` :

```
select id, name, l.*
from log_data, lateral populate_log(message) as l;
```

I suppose that `message` column is a text, in Postgres it might be an array, in that case you have to remove some conversions, `string_to_array(substring(populate_log.data))` -> `populate_log.data`